# Changing text size of an Android Spinner dynamically at runtime

Tags: android, dynamic, runtime, spinner, android-spinner

I am trying to set the text size of a spinner dynamically in the program. I am using the below code. The text size changes but due to some reason, the spinner always shows the item at index 0 even though the database has a different value and I am using setSelection method to update the selection based on the database. Below is my code. Am I doing something wrong?

```
    mAutoBackup = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.auto_backup);
    final CharSequence [] autoBackupValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.auto_backup_options); 
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_header, autoBackupValues){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (v instanceof TextView)
                ((TextView) v).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, normalTextSize);
            return v;
        }
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (v instanceof TextView)
                ((TextView) v).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, normalTextSize);
            return v;
        }
    };
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    mAutoBackup.setAdapter(adapter);


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/spinner_header"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="left"
   android:textSize="22sp"
   android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: What is spinner_header ? Are you sure it is a TextView or it has a TextView ?

Comment: @Snicolas...Yes spinner_header is just a text view.. Sorry, I missed that earlier

Comment: so you pass in the if (instanceof) ?

Comment: Yes.. While debugging more I found that the overridden getView is called with a position 0 instead of the position I am setting using the Spinner.setSelection method.. Still trying to check thru the Android sources to see what could be the problem...

Comment: Do you call notifiyDataSetChanged on your adapter ?

Comment: Why would I call that? I don't change the data on the adapter after initialization..

Comment: That would trigger a view refresh..

Comment: So you mean I should call notifyDataset.... after setting the selection?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19591/discussion-between-sriman-and-snicolas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Due to an error in the flow of the code, after setting the value on the spinner, I was calling again the piece of code shown above that creates the adapter and sets it to the spinner. Fixed that flow and the world is GREEN....